# How to align tkinter widgets if columnspan has been invoked

Tags: tkinter

In this tkinter app I want *label_two* to abut *ent_text_one*

It does this if the length of *ent_text_two* is less than or equal to the length of *ent_text_one* and *label_two* combined. But if it is greater, then *label_two* appears to be right aligned in column 2. How can I fix this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def main():
    # Create the app's main window and loop
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('500x400')
    root.title('Test gui')
    mainframe = _create_main_frame(root)
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
    root.mainloop()

def _create_main_frame(container):
    frame = ttk.Frame(container, padding=5)
    _create_gui_items(frame)
    return frame

def _create_gui_items(frame):
    lbl_test_one = ttk.Label(frame, text='Label one')
    lbl_test_one.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)

    str_value_one = tk.StringVar()
    ent_text_one = ttk.Entry(frame, width=10, textvariable=str_value_one)
    ent_text_one.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

    lbl_test_two = ttk.Label(frame, text='Label two')
    lbl_test_two.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.E)

    lbl_test_three = ttk.Label(frame, text='Label three')
    lbl_test_three.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    str_value_two = tk.StringVar()
    ent_text_two = ttk.Entry(frame, width=25, textvariable=str_value_two)
    ent_text_two.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Set `sticky=tk.EW` for `ent_text_one` and `sticky=tk.W` for `label_test_two`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to figure out why:) Do you want to produce and answer and I'll accept

Comment: Is it because sticky affects other cells too? Not just the cell on which it's declared